# CoreData: Accessing the instance of NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, core-data, pointers

I have 3 Scenes each collecting User's input.  Each Scene has 5 UITextFields.  The 4th Scene shows all the 15 Text Field in a UITableView.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do do this, but I have the following code for scene 1:

```
//Meetings is NSManagedObject class. Meetings.h and .m was created from the Meetings entity from Core Data
//I have this code once in the file right before I start saving the data
Meetings *meetings = (Meetings *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Meetings" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

// I have similar code below for each user's input.  
 NSString *date = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:selectedDate]];
            DateLabel.text = date;
            [meetings setDateLabel:date];
            ...
            [meetings setTimeLabel:time];
            ..

//Code below is to save.  I have this once at the end of the file to save the data
NSError *error = nil;
if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    // Handle the error.
}
//The log below shows the saved data fine.  Thus, the data is being saved in managnedObjectContext.
NSLog (@"This is the DateLabel %@", meetings.DateLabel);
```

Question: How do I access the pointer *meetings from Scene 2 and 3 to save rest of the fields in managedObjectContext?  I did a NSLog from Scene 2 and it shows as Null:

```
//In Scene 2 viewDidLoad method I did the following to check: 

self.managedObjectContext = [(STAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]  delegate] managedObjectContext];
Meetings *meetings = (Meetings *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Meetings" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
NSLog (@"This is the DateLabel from Scene 2 %@", meetings.DateLabel);
```

The log shows:

```
2013-02-11 18:04:05.447 MyApp[3505:c07] This is the DateLabel from Scene 2 (null)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to pass a pointer to the Meetings object from the previous screens forward to the next by storing them in a property, or you can pass the object's id's and fetch them as needed for the final screen.

Assume the following is a reflection of your code. The class names may not be identical, but I think you will be able follow and change them as needed.

**Scene 1 Header File:**

```
//
//  Scene1ViewController.h
// ... etc.

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Meetings.h"

@interface Scene1ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) Meetings *meetingsForScene1;
// ... etc.
@end
```

**Scene 2 Header File:**

```
//
//  Scene2ViewController.h
//  ... etc.

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Meetings.h"

@interface Scene2ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) Meetings *meetingsFromScene1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Meetings *meetingsForScene2;
//  ... etc.
@end
```

*`meetingsForScene2` may or may not be appropriate depending on your requirements. You might just add data from Scene2 to the `meetingsFromScene1` and pass that instance on to the next scene.*

**Scene 1 Implementation's `-prepareForSegue:sender:`:**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YourSegueIdentifierForTransistionFromScene1ToScene2"]) {
        Scene2ViewController *scene2 = [destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[Scene2ViewController class]] ? (Scene2ViewController *)destinationViewController : nil;

        NSAssert(scene2, @"scene2 should not be nil");
        NSAssert(self.meetingsForScene1, @"self.meetingsForSecen1 should not be nil");

        scene2.meetingsFromScene1 = self.meetingsForScene1;
    }
}
```

Note you might have two properties on Scene2. One for the current scene's data and one for the previous scene's data. The important property is the one that holds the data from the previous scene. The `-prepareForSegue:sender:` method in Scene1 is an appropriate time to set Scene1's data to the property on Scene2.

I've included some `NSAssert` calls to do some checking. Consider removing those in your production code. Also, note the check when assigning `*scene2`. If your destination controller is not the right "kind", you'll find out right away.

I am not necessarily advocating this approach as the "best" for your problem, but this approach will at least provide a path to a solution, if not address the issue entirely.

Comment: I created a property in Scene 1: property (strong, nonatomic) Meetings *meetings; I synthesized it. I imported Scene1.h into Scene 2. I created a property in Scene 2: @property (Strong, nonatomic) Scene1 *scene1 I synthesized it. Next, I removed the following line from viewDidLoad in Scene 2: LetsMeet *letsMeet = (LetsMeet *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"LetsMeet" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]; Now, when I do this in Scene 2: NSLog (@"This is the DateLabel from Scene 1 %@", scene1.meetings.DateLabel); I still get NULL

Comment: I'd venture to say, if you checked the property scene1 on your Scene2 view controller, you'd find it's null. Change your property on Scene2 to hold an instance of Meetings. On Scene1, during the prepare for segue message, set that property on the Scene2 to the Meetings data from Scene1 (of course, populate the data from the form). Don't try to store a reference to the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you do in your viewDidLoad method is creating a new object in your NSManagedObjectContext instance.

What you should do is to make a fetch request for your previously created Meetings object.

Maybe you should read a tutorial about Core Data. The following is very easy to understand: http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have seen that raywenderlich's tutorial.  I'm actually doing Apple's Core Data iOS Tutorial.  As I'm doing that, I'm also trying to complete my App in steps.  

I have to create a fetch request even if I'm really don't have a need in Scene 2 and 3? I plan on doing the fetch request in Scene 4 to display the collected data in UITableView.  

In Scene 2 and 3, all I need to do is continue to save data to other fields?  

How can I get access to that *meetings pointer in Scene 1 from Scene 2 and 3?  Thanks.

Comment: You can still create a property in your scene 2. For example, @property Meetings *myMeeting; And just before your push your scene 2, you set its myMeeting property to be a pointer to your previously created meetings object.

Comment: I created a property in Scene 1:
property (strong, nonatomic) Meetings *meetings;

I synthesized it.  I imported Scene1.h into Scene 2.
I created a property in Scene 2:

    @property (Strong, nonatomic) Scene1 *scene1

I synthesized it.  Next, I removed the following line from viewDidLoad in Scene 2:
     LetsMeet *letsMeet = (LetsMeet *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"LetsMeet" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

Now, when I do this in Scene 2:
        NSLog (@"This is the DateLabel from Scene 1 %@", scene1.meetings.DateLabel);

I still get NULL

Comment: Have you set the scene1 property of the scene 2 to be a pointer to your scene 1 object ? Right before you make this: [yourNavigationController pushViewController:scene2 animated:YES]; you should do this [scene2 setScene1:scene1]; Of course, this may differ depending on the organization of your code.

Comment: You mean set the pointer of Scene 2 in Scene in PreparForSegue method?

I'm sorry I'm confused.  What will that do?  What do you mean by [scene2 setScene2:scene1]?  Thanks.

Comment: If you use storyboard, you should indeed use the prepareForSegue method.

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        Scene2 *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.scene1 = self;
    }
}

Comment: I put your code in prepareForSegue and it doesn't seem to work.  It keeps saying that Property 'meetings' not found on object of type "Meetings *"   I tried the following code NSLog (@"This is the Datelabel from Scene 1 %@", scene1.meetings.DateLabel)  I even tried self.meetings.DateLabel and still no luck.

Comment: @user1107173 on scene2 do you have a property for scene1's Meetings?

Comment: Perhaps the conversation is better continued in a [chat (IOS Beginners)](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19284/ios-beginners). Join the chat and we can discuss a solution to your dilemma.

Comment: @user1107173 have you figured out a solution to your problem?

Comment: @seanwoodward  I haven't figured out a solution yet.  Based on some research, I'm thinking passing the Core Data instance ObjectID would be a better solution.  I have started to read a core data book.  I will post a solution once I have it working.  I'll be around Monday and would love to Chat.  Sorry about the delayed response.  I have been tied up with school .  Thank you for follow-up.

Comment: @user1107173, I don't think you need to go to the trouble of fetching the managed object again on the following scenes. Simply setting a reference to the one used by the current scene on a property of the second scene should be sufficient. I'm confident a little effort will get the data you need from one scene to the next. Pop in the chat, a better place for a back and forth conversation of this type, say, "hello". I'll look for you there.